# Get value of an text input defined by variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of an input text field using

```
var $rel = '#'+$(this).attr('rel');
```

but it returns nothing when I test it with

```
alert($rel.val());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/59VmX/

Comment: Just use `this.rel` instead of `$(this).attr('rel')` and wrap it in jquery to get val().

Comment: Don't forget to include the jquery library in the `Frameworks & Extensions` when using jQuery with jsFiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'#'+$(this).attr('rel');  // This is just a string
```

supposed to be

```
$('#'+$(this).attr('rel'));  OR // $('#'+ this.rel);
```

You need to encase it as a jQuery object if you want to use `val` method on the object

Comment: Or even better: `$('#' + this.rel)`

Comment: @Itay. According to the code the OP provided, I believe he was trying to access a input with id of that rel attribute.

Comment: When I try to do an alert to test it, there is no value. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/59VmX/6/

Comment: That is because you do not have a input that has the id set to the rel attribute

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/59VmX/8.. Also make sure you select the jQuery framework in options on left.

Comment: Sorry, never mind. It does work -- I just have an issue elsewhere on the page that is causing an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @badke.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.val()` Try just `alert($rel);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/KcaSJ/) , In your old fiddle ,`jquery` is not loaded and:

**Instead of this :**

```
 var $rel = '#'+$(this).attr('rel');
 alert($rel.val());
```

**It should be :**

```
 var $rel = $(this).attr('rel');
 alert($rel);
```